# URL Scheme: what kind of string results

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, url-scheme, marmalade

I'm using Marmalade to develop iOS applications via VisualStudio and a PC. The integration of a social feature like HeyZap needs its initialization by the use of:

```
loadHeyzap("YOUR_APP_ID_HERE","YOUR_APP_URL_HERE", true);
```

App_ID is the ID as defined in the itunes app page (I got it).

App_URL "should also similarly be replaced with your URL scheme for the iPhone" [from the HeyZap integration doc].

Well, the HeyZap help desk weren't useful to obtain this string via the use of VisualStudio+PC (in fact, they told me "use XCode+Mac instead...").
Since this is a simple string, I suppose I could obtain it starting from known parameters of my app. I suppose to find inside it something like [app_name]&=other-chars-....

Is there a way to build this string without the use of XCode, just starting from info I already have and putting here and there some special chars? 
In other words, is there a standard way to automate the build of this string without the neeed to do it via XCode? I wonder to prepare a function in which I would pass my app parameters and I got the URL Scheme string as a result.

Cheers,

Zapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL scheme is most probably the url of your app in App Store. You can obtain it from iTunesConnect. Go to your application and copy the url of `View in App Store` link. That's the string you wanted ;-)

Let me know if it doesn't work.

**Edit:**
Well App url worked for me, dunno why its not working for you. If you want to edit the URL scheme, you can do it without using XCode too. You need to include Info.plist file in the mkb settings. You can edit or check the current URL scheme being used by marmalade there. The default plist file is in the s3e folder. Don't know the exact location.

Comment: Well it started working but definitively it didn't :( I think I should find another way to build this string without a Mac

Comment: Ok, I don't know why but it's working now using your first suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Creator is incorrect. A URL schema is how apps can communicate with each other in iOS.

*Here is what Apple has to say*
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899

An example would be:
yourgame://

*Here's how you would define one in XCode*

When you define a URL schema in XCode, you can call that URL from Safari or any app installed on the device and it will switch to your game.

The way you define it in XCode is by going to your project settings, clicking the Info tab at the top, going to the bottom where it says "URL Types", expand that, and click the + button at the bottom. Then define both the identifier and the URL schemes with something reasonably unique like "yourgamename". Done!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxEKd.png

Comment: Thank you drhodes. Well, my problem is that I develop using a PC and I need to find a way to build this string using my PC. How may I do without the use of XCode?